# iScroll4, iPad, fixed element. How to attach element to the top. Example included

Tags: ios, css, html, css-position, iscroll

I'm making a website using iScroll4 (cuz I need animations while scrolling on iOS devices) and at a some point, element becomes fixed but it won't work with iScroll4 or I doing something wrong.

So, I used jQuery transit for translateY and I just moving element at the actual scroll position, but this making my element flicker.

Look (scroll a little down) http://danielsitarz.pl/tests/iwanttobefixed/

And I need help, maybe somebody know how to make position:fixed working or make translateY more smooth.

On desktops I don't using iScroll4 but I need this on iPad etc.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Okay, after many travels to work in bus I found an answer.

Just throw element outside iScroll wrapper and then set fixed position to him.

Like that:

```
$('#wrapper').after(elementThatWantsToBeFixed);
$(elementThatWantsToBeFixed).css({position: 'fixed'});
```